# Sending and receiving a message between the wireless nodes under NS2

Tags: tcl, ns2

I have a wireless network in NS2, and I want to communicate between the nodes by control messages that I define their contents.
So I want to know how I can send and receive these messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example text message https://ramakrishnamundugar.blogspot.dk/p/tcl-script-to-demonstrate-message.html The trace file four.tr will read ...

```
.
v 68.915850808760979 eval {set sim_annotation {1 received {how are you}}}
.
v 68.915850808760979 eval {set sim_annotation {question: how are you. answer: fine}}
.
v 70.508104551724557 eval {set sim_annotation {0 received {hi}}}
.
v 70.508104551724557 eval {set sim_annotation {question: hi. answer: Thanks}}
```

Nam: `$ nam four.nam` shows some text in the terminal, during the animation ...

More information: Please use Google.
Keywords : `ns2 send message` , and: `ns2 send video`

Comment: Thank you for your help, I understand the operation of this program that you send me.
First I want to trigger an action if I receive some message, for example, change the color of the node that receives such a message.
and thank you